# Mongo chokes with 'login failed' when trying to login with user and pwd

Tags: mongodb, authentication, authorization, database

The user 'tyuser' has been added to the system.users collection in the admin database:

```
{user: 'tyuser',
 pwd: 'typwd',
 roles: [{role: 'readWrite', db: 'testy'}]}
```

mongod is then started with `mongod --auth`

When trying `mongo testy -u tyuser -p typwd`

mongo barfs with "exception: login failed"

What is the correct way to access my 'testy' database as an authenticated user?

Comment: First thing is that I hadn't created the user with 'createUser'. After deleting this document from system.users in the admin database, I then created user tyuser using db.createUser. Secondly, I then added an additional role "{role: 'readWrite', db:'admin'}". This then allowed me to login: "mongo admin -u tyuser -p typwd". Then I switched databases with "use testy" and now have read/write access.

Comment: So now my question is why did I have to add readWrite access to the admin database? Isn't there a way to access testy directly without having to login to the admin db?